# How to round to nearest 5 on second decimal place

Tags: java, math, decimal, rounding, decimalformat

I need to make a program that rounds the second decimal place up or down to the nearest 5 for example, 13.14 to 13.15. I've looked everywhere to find out how to use the math.round() command but can't find it. Decimal format would work as well since I have to change the value into a string anyway.

Comment: Remember, you can multiply by 100 so you aren't working with decimals, and use modulo division

Answer (score 2):

Rounding to 0.05 is equivalent to rounding to the nearest 1/20. To round to any 1/n, just multiply by n, round to an integer, then divide (with non-integer division) by n. Something like `Math.round(x * 20.0) / 20.0` seems like enough.

EDIT: If it becomes important that the result be exactly rounded, you might want to try to do the final division on instances of `java.math.BigDecimal` or some other decimal implementation.

Comment: If you're using BigDecimal anyway (for that final division) you may just want to use BigDecimal for the whole thing, because you can set the precision and the rounding mode you want. See for example the [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) class.